# How to get text and replace text between certain tags

Tags: python, html, regex, html-parsing

Given a string like

```
"<p> >this line starts with an arrow <br /> this line does not </p>"
```

or

```
"<p> >this line starts with an arrow </p> <p> this line does not </p>"
```

How can I find the lines that start with an arrow and surround them with a div

So that it becomes:

```
"<p> <div> >this line starts with an arrow </div> <br /> this line does not </p>
```

Comment: How do you define "line"?

Comment: Go with [@alexcxe's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24391725/2461379) answer because, well...[I'll just leave this here...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2461379)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since it is an HTML you are parsing, use the tool for the job - an HTML parser, like [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Use [`find_all()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) to find all text nodes that start with `>` and [`wrap()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#wrap) them with a new `div` tag:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = "<p> >this line starts with an arrow <br /> this line does not </p>"

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
for item in soup.find_all(text=lambda x: x.strip().startswith('>')):
    item.wrap(soup.new_tag('div'))

print soup.prettify()
```

Prints:

```
<p>
    <div>
    >this line starts with an arrow
    </div>
    <br/>
    this line does not
</p>
```

Comment: +1. When I clicked on this question, I was really worried that there was going to be something about a regular expression...

Answer (score 3):

You can try with `>\s+(>.*?)<` regex pattern.

```
import re
regex = re.compile("\\>\\s{1,}(\\>.{0,}?)\\<")
testString = "" # fill this in
matchArray = regex.findall(testString)
# the matchArray variable contains the list of matches
```

and replace matched group with `<div> matched_group </div>`. Here pattern look for anything that is enclosed inside `> >` and `<`.

Here is demo on [debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/jimbr72JrXShSE4A)

Answer (score 1):

You could try this regex,

```
>(\w[^<]*)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/aP8wF0)

Python code would be,

```
>>> import re
>>> str = '"<p> >this line starts with an arrow <br /> this line does not </p>"'
>>> m = re.sub(r'>(\w[^<]*)', r"<div> >\1</div> ", str)
>>> m
'"<p> <div> >this line starts with an arrow </div> <br /> this line does not </p>"'
```